# Fancybox thumbnail position relative to current image

Tags: fancybox

I'm using fancybox 2.0.6 and trying to figure out a way to get the thumbnail strip to stay either relative to the current image- it needs to be more visible as opposed to the bottom of larger browser windows.

I've used the `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css` to adjust the `bottom: 120px` which helps but if the browser window is smaller the thumbs obstruct the current image.

The only jquery options I've seen are "top" or "bottom".

Any thoughts on keeping it relative to the image without it changing on different sized windows?